# Keep getting this error: The event 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Tags: c#, wpf

I keep getting this error when making the program as given below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace simplecalc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int a, b, c;
            a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            if (rbadd.Checked == true)
                c = a + b;
            else if (rbsubtract.Checked == true)
                c = a - b;
            else if (rbdivide.Checked == true)
                c = a / b;
            else
                c = a * b;
            textBox3.Text = c.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I am in the process of making a basic calculator in C# in WPF. I am very new to C#.

Comment: Just curious, why +2 for this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Checked` here is an **event**, not a `bool`, that happens *when* it is checked. You need a different property - presumably [`IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx).

Minor note, but stylistically, it is usually preferable not to compare booleans to `true`/`false`, but rather:

```
        if (rbadd.IsChecked)
            c = a + b;
        else if (rbsubtract.IsChecked)
            c = a - b;
        else if (rbdivide.IsChecked)
            c = a / b;
```

etc; or if you wanted to test for `false`: `if(!rbadd.IsChecked)`.

Comment: Please note that this won't compile, because the type of the IsChecked property is `bool?`. Cast to bool like `if ((bool)rbadd.IsChecked)`.